# inputs rederizados por un map, como guardar los datos de cada uno de los inputs en un state diferente?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy haciendo una practica en react soy principiante y tengo esta incógnita, en esta practica tengo unos inputs que se renderizan de manera dinamica por un map, como haría para que cada dato de cada uno de los inputs renderizados se guarde en un state diferente. este es mi código hasta los momentos, gracias de antemano.

```js
export class RenderizadoPrueba extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      values: '',
      nroRenderElemento: 3,
      inputs: []
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
        value: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    console.log('Este es el nombre introducido:', this.state.value);
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
      inputs: [... Array(this.state.nroRenderElemento)].map((input, i) =>
        <label key={input}>
          Introduzca su Nombre:
          <input type="text" name={i} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </label>
      )
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div> 
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {this.state.inputs}
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acá te dejo como quedaría, algunas cosas a tener en cuenta

- Los valores los estoy guardando en un array, con el mismo index que
  el del input.
- Usé el metodo `slice` en el array de values para hacer
  un `shallow` copy del array y para no mutarlo. Lo modifico y luego lo
  reemplazo por el anterior.
- También cambié la llamada del callback
  `onChange` creando una funcion anonima para poder pasarle un
  parametro extra que es el index.

```js
class RenderizadoPrueba extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      values: [],
      nroRenderElemento: 3,
      inputs: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e, index) {
    const values = this.state.values.slice();
    values[index] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({values});
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    console.log("Este es el nombre introducido:", this.state.value);
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      inputs: [...Array(this.state.nroRenderElemento)].map((input, i) => (
        <label key={input}>
          Introduzca su Nombre:
          <input type="text" name={i} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, i)} />
        </label>
      ))
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {this.state.inputs}
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<RenderizadoPrueba />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, :D